# Check if Immutable.js map value contains char

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I was wondering if there was an easy way to check if a immutable map value contains a certain char.

Basically looking for https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/includes but that only matches whole words on the value.

Right now I iterate through every property and check the value itself.

```
function mapContains(map, char) {
  let contains = false;
  map.forEach((val) => {
    if(val.includes(char)) {
      contains = true;
      return false; //short circuits the foreach
    }
  });
  return contains;
}
```

Thanks for the response in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `Map.prototype.some` for this. It will short-circuit and return `true` as soon as your lambda returns a truthy value – otherwise it returns `false`

```
const { Map } = require('immutable')

const m = Map({a: 'one', b: 'two', c: 'three'})

m.some(v => /t/.test(v)) // true, at least one value has a 't'
m.some(v => /x/.text(v)) // false, no values contain an 'x'

// but be careful with automatic string coercion
/o/.test({}) // true, because String({}), '[object Object]', contains 'o'
```

If your Map will hold multiple value *types*, you will want to be careful with using a `String.prototype` methods – ie, I would advise against something like this

```
const { Map } = require('immutable')

// mixed value type Map
const m = Map({a: 'one', b: 2, c: 3})

// CAUTION!
// reckless assumption that every value is a string (or has a .includes method)
m.some(v => v.includes('o')) // true, short-circuits on first value
m.some(v => v.includes('x')) // TypeError: v.includes is not a function
```

If you must use `String.prototype.includes`, I would recommend you do `type` checking first

```
const { Map } = require('immutable')

const m = Map({a: 'one', b: 2, c: 3})

m.some(v => typeof v === 'string' && v.includes('o')) // true
m.some(v => typeof v === 'string' && v.includes('x')) // fase
```

Comment: Awesome! Great suggestion on the includes.